# excel 2013 vba code statement to Convert a table numeric cell type (2,4) into text cell type D2

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am struggling to try writing an excel 2013 vba code statement to Convert a table cell type (2,4) into a cell type "D2", I tried the following statement:

```
dim celdactiva as range

with mcard  **(this is an excel objectlist that contains cell(2,4))**

set celdactiva=.Cells(2, 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
to returns "D2". **But the part (RowAbsolute:=False , Pups up as error)**

end with
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is really on the `Set` part.  `Address` returns a `String`.  If you want to store this `String` in `celdactiva` then you need to change the declaration type from `Range` to `String` and remove the `Set` down below.

```
Dim celdactiva as String

With mcard
   celdactiva=.Cells(2, 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
End With
```

Comment: thanks so much. I'll see later what happens. keep in contact. let "U" know

Comment: hi. after i succeeded getting celdactiva equal to a text cell type i failed putting this text back into a variable ( rango as range ). as fallow:

Comment: dim rango as range {of my table (mcard)}

Comment: dim rango as range                                                                                     with mcard                                                                                                           set rango=.range("celdactiva")                                                                           --this shows invalid procedure message. why?

Comment: Did you leave the quotes on it?  It should be `Range(celdactiva)`.

Comment: yes. I tried with none quotes and shows error 5"invalid procedure"

Comment: I would ask a new question and post the full code then.  Or edit this question with the full code, but it sounds like a new/different issue.